# Adding the single product template add to cart to a lightbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the  add to cart button that appears on the woocommerce single product template to work in a lightbox.

I am able to get it to show up using the `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart()` function, however when I click on it, rather then redirect to cart page, it redirects to the the single product page.

What code am I missing?

Comment: how can we tell if we don't even know what's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in your function.php

```
if ( !function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' ) ) { 
 require_once '/includes/wc-template-functions.php'; 
}
```